# How to create infinite scroll in React and Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

> ```
> import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
> import {connect} from 'react-redux';
>
> import {
>     fetchRecipes
> } from '../../store/actions';
> import './BeerRecipes.css';
>
> const BeerRecipes = ({recipesData, fetchRecipes}) => {
>
>     const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
>     const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
>     const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
>
>
>     useEffect(() => {
>         fetchRecipes();
>     }, [])
>
>     return (
>
>                 <div className='beer_recipes_block'>
>                     <div className='title_wrapper'>
>                         <h2 className='title'>Beer recipes</h2>
>                     </div>
>                     <div className='beer_recipes'>
>                         <ul className='beer_recipes_items'>
>                             {
>                                 recipesData && recipesData.recipes && recipesData.recipes.map(recipe =>
>                                     <li className='beer_recipes_item' id={recipe.id}>{recipe.name}</li>
>                                 )
>                             }
>                         </ul>
>                     </div>
>                 </div>
>
>     );
> };
>
> const mapStateToProps = state => {
>     return {
>         recipesData: state.recipes
>     }
> }
>
> const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
>     return {
>         fetchRecipes: () => dispatch(fetchRecipes())
>     }
> }
>
> export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BeerRecipes);
> ```

this is my component where I would like to create infinite scroll and below is my redux-action with axios:

> ```
> import axios from "axios";
> import * as actionTypes from "./actionTypes";
>
> export const fetchRecipesRequest = () => {
>     return {
>         type: actionTypes.FETCH_RECIPES_REQUEST
>     }
> }
>
> export const fetchRecipesSuccess = recipes => {
>     return {
>         type: actionTypes.FETCH_RECIPES_SUCCESS,
>         payload: recipes
>     }
> }
>
> export const fetchRecipesFailure = error => {
>     return {
>         type: actionTypes.FETCH_RECIPES_FAILURE,
>         payload: error
>     }
> }
>
> export const fetchRecipes = (page) => {
>    return (dispatch) => {
>        dispatch(fetchRecipesRequest)
>         axios
>             .get('https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?page=1')
>             .then(response => {
>                 const recipes = response.data;
>                 dispatch(fetchRecipesSuccess(recipes));
>             })
>             .catch(error => {
>                 const errorMsg = error.message;
>                 dispatch(fetchRecipesFailure(errorMsg));
>             })
>    }
> }
> ```

I want to create a scroll. I need, firstly, to display first 10 elements and then to add 5 elements with every loading. I have 25 elements altogether and when the list is done it should start from the first five again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have everything ready to load your next page. You can probably simplify the entire process by using a package like [react-in-viewport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-in-viewport) so you don't have to deal with all the scroll listeners.

then you use it like this way.

```
import handleViewport from 'react-in-viewport';
 
const Block = (props: { inViewport: boolean }) => {
  const { inViewport, forwardedRef } = props;
  const color = inViewport ? '#217ac0' : '#ff9800';
  const text = inViewport ? 'In viewport' : 'Not in viewport';
  return (
    <div className="viewport-block" ref={forwardedRef}>
      <h3>{ text }</h3>
      <div style={{ width: '400px', height: '300px', background: color }} />
    </div>
  );
};
 
const ViewportBlock = handleViewport(Block, /** options: {}, config: {} **/);
 
const Component = (props) => (
  <div>
    <div style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
      <h2>Scroll down to make component in viewport</h2>
    </div>
    <ViewportBlock 
         onEnterViewport={() => console.log('This is the bottom of the content, lets dispatch to load more post ')} 
         onLeaveViewport={() => console.log('We can choose not to use this.')} />
  </div>
))
```

What happen here is, it creates a 'div' which is outside the viewport, once it comes into the view port ( it means user already scrolled to the bottom ), you can call a function to load more post.

To Note: Remember to add some kind of throttle to your fetch function.