# I need to create infinite scroll in React and Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

> ```
> import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
> import {connect} from 'react-redux';
>
> import {
>     fetchRecipes
> } from '../../store/actions';
> import './BeerRecipes.css';
>
> const BeerRecipes = ({recipesData, fetchRecipes}) => {
>
>     useEffect(() => {
>         fetchRecipes();
>     }, [])
>
>     return (
>
>                 <div className='beer_recipes_block'>
>                     <div className='title_wrapper'>
>                         <h2 className='title'>Beer recipes</h2>
>                     </div>
>                     <div className='beer_recipes'>
>                         <ul className='beer_recipes_items'>
>                             {
>                                 recipesData && recipesData.recipes &&.recipesData.recipes.map(recipe =>
>                                     <li className='beer_recipes_item' id={recipe.id}>{recipe.name}</li>
>                                 )
>                             }
>                         </ul>
>                     </div>
>                 </div>
>
>     );
> };
>
> const mapStateToProps = state => {
>     return {
>         recipesData: state.recipes
>     }
> }
>
> const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
>     return {
>         fetchRecipes: () => dispatch(fetchRecipes())
>     }
> }
>
> export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BeerRecipes);
> ```

this is my component where I would like to create infinite scroll and below is my redux-action with axios:

> ```
> import axios from "axios";
> import * as actionTypes from "./actionTypes";
>
> export const fetchRecipesRequest = () => {
>     return {
>         type: actionTypes.FETCH_RECIPES_REQUEST
>     }
> }
>
> export const fetchRecipesSuccess = recipes => {
>     return {
>         type: actionTypes.FETCH_RECIPES_SUCCESS,
>         payload: recipes
>     }
> }
>
> export const fetchRecipesFailure = error => {
>     return {
>         type: actionTypes.FETCH_RECIPES_FAILURE,
>         payload: error
>     }
> }
>
> export const fetchRecipes = (page) => {
>    return (dispatch) => {
>        dispatch(fetchRecipesRequest)
>         axios
>             .get('https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?page=1')
>             .then(response => {
>                 const recipes = response.data;
>                 dispatch(fetchRecipesSuccess(recipes));
>             })
>             .catch(error => {
>                 const errorMsg = error.message;
>                 dispatch(fetchRecipesFailure(errorMsg));
>             })
>    }
> }
> ```

I want to create a scroll. I need, firstly, to display first 10 elements and then to add 5 elements with every loading. I have 25 elements altogether and when the list is done it should start from the first five again.

Comment: why you asking twice. I already answered you in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65086880/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-in-react-and-redux/65086963#65086963

Comment: Sorry! I don't understand the answer. I dont't know how to use it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create infinite scroll in React and Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65086880/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-in-react-and-redux)

Comment: creating a duplicating post doesn't make you suddenly learn how to try answers. You need to do follow ups